# Images are not being stored for html5 2D canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

picture: http://oi43.tinypic.com/qzou2r.jpg

I was learning how to code a simple 2D tile engine, and one of the ways I learn best is by trying to make the same program but in a different way and then tinkering with it.  Anywho, I was following this tutorial: http://that-guy.net/articles/2/Javascript-tile-engine-map-with-images/ and my code is not working, it says the file is unidentified or something and fills up the canvas with errors.  The first tutorial of his (the one before) I can get it working with the way I set up my application, but for some reason this way isnt working.  I kinda know what the problem is but unsure how to fix it and I was wondering if you guys could help.  Ill comment the section I think is the problem with: * * *

```
var engine = {
outhnd: document.getElementById('output'),
canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
handle: this.canvas.getContext('2d'),
width: this.canvas.width,
height: this.canvas.height,
tilesX: this.canvas.width / 16,
tilesY: this.canvas.height / 16,
images: 0, // *** I think this is what is causing the problem with the TILESTORE.

output: function (message) {
    engine.outhnd.innerHTML += '<br />' + message;
},
start: function (mapData, x, y) {
    engine.handle.translate( 0, 8 );
    engine.output('starting...');
    engine.viewport.x = x;
    engine.viewport.y = y;

    engine.tilestore('g', 'tile_grass.png');
    engine.tilestore('r', 'tile_rockgrass.png');
    engine.tilestore(' ', 'tile_black.png');

    engine.draw(mapData);
    engine.output('done');
},
viewport: function () {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
},
allLoaded: function () {
    var i, len = engine.images.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if(engine.images[i][2] === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
},
draw: function (mapData) {
    if(engine.allLoaded() === false){
        setTimeout(function(md)
    {
     return function() {
        engine.output('[engine.draw] waiting for images...');
        engine.draw(md);
    }
    }(mapData), 100);
    }else{
        engine.drawmap(mapData);
    }

},
drawmap: function (mapData) {
    var i, j;

    var mapX = 0;
    var mapY = 0;
    var tile;

    engine.output('drawing map from ' + engine.viewport.x + ',' + engine.viewport.y + ' to ' +
    (engine.viewport.x + engine.tilesX) + ',' + (engine.viewport.y + engine.tilesY));
    for(j=0; j<engine.tilesY; j++) {
        for(i=0; i<engine.tilesX; i++) {
            mapX = i + engine.viewport.x;
            mapY = j + engine.viewport.y;

            tile = (mapData[mapY] && mapData[mapY][mapX]) ? mapData[mapY][mapX] : ' ';
            engine.tiledraw( i, j, tile);
        }
    }
},
tiledraw: function (x,y,tile){
var img = engine.tileretrieve(tile);
    engine.handle.fillText(img, x * 16, y * 16);
},
 //*** the problem ***
tilestore: function(id, imgSrc) {
    var newid = engine.images.length;
    var tile  = [id, new Image(), false];

    tile[1].src    = imgSrc;
    tile[1].onload = function() {
        tile[2] = true;
        }
    engine.images[newid] = tile;
},
tileretrieve: function(id) {
    var i, len = engine.images.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(engine.images[i][0] == id) {
            return engine.images[i][1];
        }
    }
},
};
```

Is there any reason why this doesn't work.  Why doesn't it store the image.  I'm new to java script and this might save myself from a lot of headaches.

Edit:  How I call it:

```
 var mapone =
   [
  ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
  ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']
   ];
  engine.start(mapone, 0, 5);
```

edit: gave wrong link before: http://that-guy.net/articles/2/Javascript-tile-engine-map-with-images/

**EDIT**
if anyone was interested, I have working code I wrote, and I will post here for anyone who wanted to learn a new way.  Thanks everyone for trying to help.

```
var image_holder = function () {

    this.image_id =     0;  // 'a','b', etc
    this.image_src =    0;  // the source
    this.image_type =   0;  // 0 or 1
    this.image_load =   0;  // is it loaded 0 = false 1 = true
    this._head =        null;
};
image_holder.prototype = {

add: function (image_id, image_src, image_type, image_load) {

    var node = {
        image_id:image_id,
        image_src:image_src,
        image_type:image_type,
        image_load:image_load,
        next:null
    },
    current;

        if (this._head === null) {
            this._head = node;
        } else {
            current = this._head;

            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }   
            current.next = node;
        }

        this.image_id = image_id;
        this.image_src = image_src;
        this.image_type = image_type;
        this.image_load = image_load;

        },
get: function (image_id, image_load) {
    var current = this._head;

    if(image_id != null && image_load == null) {
        while (current != null && current.image_id != image_id) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            if(current != null){
                return current;
                }
            return null;
        }

    if(image_id == null && image_load != null) {
        while (current != null && current.image_load != image_load) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            if(current != null)
                return current;
            return null;
        }
    },
};

var engine = {
    outhnd: document.getElementById('output'),
    canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
    handle: this.canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width: this.canvas.width,
    height: this.canvas.height,
    tilesX: this.canvas.width / 16,
    tilesY: this.canvas.height / 16,
    obj: new image_holder(),

output: function (message) {
    engine.outhnd.innerHTML += '<br />' + message;
},
start: function (mapData, x, y) {
    engine.handle.translate( 0, 8 );
    engine.output('starting...');
    engine.viewport.x = x;
    engine.viewport.y = y;

    var images0 = "tile_grass.png";
    var images1 = "tile_rock.png";
    var images2 = "tile_black.png";

    imageObject0 = new Image();
    imageObject0.src = images0;
    imageObject0.onload = function() {
                        engine.obj.add('g', imageObject0, 0, 1);
                        var b = engine.obj.get('g').image_id;
                        console.log(b);
                                imageObject1 = new Image();
                                imageObject1.src = images1;
                                imageObject1.onload = function() {
                                engine.obj.add('r', imageObject1, 0, 1);
                                        imageObject2 = new Image();
                                        imageObject2.src = images2;
                                        imageObject2.onload = function() {
                                        engine.obj.add(' ', imageObject2, 0, 1);
                                        engine.draw(mapData);
                                        engine.output('done');
                                        };                              
                                };
                        };
},
viewport: function () {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
},
draw: function (mapData) {
    engine.drawmap(mapData);
},
drawmap: function (mapData) {
    var i, j;
    var mapX = 0;
    var mapY = 0;
    var tile;

    engine.output('drawing map from ' + engine.viewport.x + ',' + engine.viewport.y + ' to ' +
    (engine.viewport.x + engine.tilesX) + ',' + (engine.viewport.y + engine.tilesY));
    for(j=0; j<engine.tilesY; j++) {
        for(i=0; i<engine.tilesX; i++) {
            mapX = i + engine.viewport.x;
            mapY = j + engine.viewport.y;

            tile = (mapData[mapY] && mapData[mapY][mapX]) ? mapData[mapY][mapX] : ' ';
            engine.tiledraw( i, j, tile);
        }
    }
},
tiledraw: function (x,y,tile){
    var img = engine.obj.get(tile,null).image_src;
    engine.handle.drawImage(img, x * 16, y * 16);
},
};


CALL:

        var mapone = [
        ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'r'],
        ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']];
        engine.start(mapone, 0, 5);
```

Comment: is your html file on a webserver on your computer, like IIS or XAMPP? if the address of your file starts with file: you may not be able to access the canvas image

Comment: I am running WAMP on this computer, and its all in the same folder, so it has access.

Comment: I uploaded a picture (just a small one 100x100 or so) of what it produces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue your encountering is because you instantiate `images = 0`
and then later try 
    `var newid = engine.images.length;`
this is trying to get a length of the images array but images is currently holding an int.
Maybe try instantiating images like
    `images = []`

Comment: When I do that it spams: "[engine.draw] waiting for images..."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 'images=0' isn't right.  It just needs to be an array.

```
images = [],
```

The second problem is that you're not calling the correct canvas method.  Change your tileDraw method to:

```
tiledraw: function (x,y,tile){
var img = engine.tileretrieve(tile);
    engine.handle.drawImage(img, x * 16, y * 16);
},
```

You still have it set to fillText.

It looks like you just forgot to update that part of the code when you moved onto the next tutorial.

To help you in the future, F12 will open the developer tools for most browsers (you need to install FireBug on FireFox).  The Console tab will show you JavaScript errors with line numbers to help you debug.  You can even set breakpoints to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: Oh thanks so much.  It still gives the error, but if I change the top to: images: images = [],  And then if I skip the allLoaded: function(), it will only draw the tile_grass.png.